# Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI empty for Firebird

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, firebird, jboss5.x

I have trouble binding local and remote versions of service beans to the **Global JNDI** for **Firebird database**. To check whether I'm missing something I also setup a test configuration for **SQL Server** which works just fine. I'm using `jaybird-2.1.6.jar`. Something is incomplete or wrong in my Firebird JPA setup.

When I use `d20pid/D20PIDServiceBean/local` to access the local service bean I get an error saying:

```
Could not get the JNDI resource with the following JNDI name: d20pid/D20PIDServiceBean/local
```

Understandably so since it hasn't been bound.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

---

Persistence.xml part for firebird:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="D20-PID-DS">
    <jta-data-source>java:/D20-PID-DS</jta-data-source>
    <class>edu.msu.its.d20pid.ejb.entity.ProvStudent</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

Datasource file firebird details (intentionally left out credentials)

```
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>D20-PID-DS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:firebirdsql:idcard.dev.ais.msu.edu:/home2/d20/idcard.db</connection-url>
        <driver-class>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver-class>
        <user-name></user-name>
        <password></password>     
        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT CAST(1 as INTEGER) FROM rdb$database</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <track-statements>false</track-statements>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>Firebird</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
```

---

server.log on EAR deployment; local and remote for D6501ServiceBean (SQL Server) are bound but not for D20PIDServiceBean (Firebird)

```
17:10:23,318 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting boss.j2ee:ear=d20pid.ear,jar=d20pid-ejb3.jar,name=D20PIDServiceBean,service=EJB3
17:10:23,322 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: edu.msu.its.d20pid.ejb.servicebean.D20PIDServiceBean ejbName: D20PIDServiceBean
17:10:23,324 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:


17:10:23,327 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=d20pid.ear,jar=d20pid-ejb3.jar,name=D6501ServiceBean,service=EJB3
17:10:23,329 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: edu.msu.its.d20pid.ejb.servicebean.D6501ServiceBean ejbName: D6501ServiceBean
17:10:23,357 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

        d20pid/D6501ServiceBean/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
        d20pid/D6501ServiceBean/remote-edu.msu.its.d20pid.ejb.service.remote.D6501ServiceRemote - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface
        d20pid/D6501ServiceBean/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
        d20pid/D6501ServiceBean/local-edu.msu.its.d20pid.ejb.service.local.D6501ServiceLocal - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

---

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the log?

Comment: @Bosko When I deploy my EAR there aren't any but this is what I get when I try to access it via the web app: edu.msu.its.d20pid.common.ServiceFactoryException: Could not get the JNDI resource with the following JNDI name: d20pid/D20PIDServiceBean/local and javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: D20PIDServiceBean not bound

Answer (score 0):

My code is working now. I hadn't annotated the local and remote beans with @Local and @Remote. That fixed it.